# list all available sub generators in yeoman

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, yeoman, gulp

say i run `yo marionette` i get a marionette app. then i want to list all available sub generators for this generator, like this

`Marionette
  marionette:app
  marionette:collection
  marionette:collectionview
  marionette:compositeview
  marionette:controller
  marionette:itemview
  marionette:layout
  marionette:model
  marionette:region
  marionette:router
  marionette:tmpl
  marionette:view`

what is the command for that.

I am building a yeoman generator, could i implement this in the generator somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Most yoeman generators implement this in help
eg

```
:> yo aspnet --help
...
Subgenerators:

  yo aspnet:angularcontroller [options] <name>
  yo aspnet:angularcontrolleras [options] <name>
  yo aspnet:angulardirective [options] <name>
  yo aspnet:angularfactory [options] <name>
  yo aspnet:angularmodule [options] <name>
  yo aspnet:appsettings [options]
  yo aspnet:bowerjson [options]
  yo aspnet:class [options] <name>
  yo aspnet:coffeescript [options] <name>
  yo aspnet:dockerfile [options]
  yo aspnet:gitignore [options]
  yo aspnet:gruntfile [options]
  yo aspnet:gulpfile [options] <name>
  yo aspnet:htmlpage [options] <name>
  yo aspnet:interface [options] <name>
  yo aspnet:javascript [options] <name>
  yo aspnet:json [options] <name>
  yo aspnet:jsonschema [options] <name>
  yo aspnet:middleware [options] <name>
  yo aspnet:mvccontroller [options] <name>
  yo aspnet:mvcview [options] <name>
  yo aspnet:nuget [options]
  yo aspnet:packagejson [options]
  yo aspnet:program [options]
  yo aspnet:startup [options]
  yo aspnet:stylesheet [options] <name>
  yo aspnet:stylesheetless [options] <name>
  yo aspnet:stylesheetscss [options] <name>
  yo aspnet:taghelper [options] <name>
  yo aspnet:textfile [options] <name>
  yo aspnet:tfignore [options]
  yo aspnet:typescript [options] <name>
  yo aspnet:typescriptconfig [options] <name>
  yo aspnet:typescriptjsx [options] <name>
  yo aspnet:usersecrets [options] <name>
  yo aspnet:webapicontroller [options] <name>
```